# How do I get freight going from one city to another?

Tags: simcity-2013

in SimCity, I want freight to get going from my soon-to-be OmegaCo capitol, Capitol Bay West, to my region capitol, Capitol Bay Central. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is have surplus freight in the supplying city (more freight than orders) and deficit freight in the receiving city, as well as a direct road link between them.

If you're actually trying to spread Omega instead, just send the Omega trucks via the region panel.